# Hand Cursor pointing to button

Tags: delphi, cursor, firemonkey, mouse-cursor, custom-cursor

I’d like to achieve a visual effect where the mouse cursor appears as a hand (or pointing finger) that always points toward a specific button on the screen. This behavior should persist even when the actual mouse pointer is not directly over the button.

For reference, I’m aiming for an effect similar to the one demonstrated in this CodePen example: https://codepen.io/aaroniker/pen/mNWQyM, but the CodePen one is using JQuery/JavaScript as can be seen below (I need it in Delphi):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    let container = $('body'),
        element = $('.btn');

    let cursor = $('<div />').addClass('cursor').html('<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 28 28"><polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="8.2,20.9 8.2,4.9 19.8,16.5 13,16.5 12.6,16.6 "/><polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="17.3,21.6 13.7,23.1 9,12 12.7,10.5 "/><rect x="12.5" y="13.6" transform="matrix(0.9221 -0.3871 0.3871 0.9221 -5.7605 6.5909)" width="2" height="8"/><polygon points="9.2,7.3 9.2,18.5 12.2,15.6 12.6,15.5 17.4,15.5 "/></svg>').appendTo(container)

    container.css('cursor', 'none');

    $(document).on('mousemove', e => {
        cursor.toggle($(e.target).is(container));
        cursor.css({
            '--x': e.pageX + 'px',
            '--y': e.pageY + 'px',
            '--r': calculateRotate(cursor, element) + 20 + 'deg'
        });
    });
    
    container.on('mouseleave', e => {
       cursor.hide(); 
    });

    function calculateRotate(elem, to) {
        let offset = elem.offset(),
            toOffset = to.offset(),
            center = {
                x: offset.left + elem.outerWidth() / 2,
                y: offset.top + elem.outerHeight() / 2
            },
            toCenter = {
                x: toOffset.left + to.outerWidth() / 2,
                y: toOffset.top + to.outerHeight() / 2
            },
            radians = Math.atan2(toCenter.x - center.x, toCenter.y - center.y),
            degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 180;
        return degree;
    }

    element.click(e => {
        return false;
    })

});
```

How can I implement this in Delphi FMX? Are there any built-in functions or libraries that allow me to customize the cursor behavior in this way?

Comment: I don't know of such packages, but you could probably achieve this option by adding your own markers to the program (pointing in different directions such as straight or diagonal, etc.) and handling MouseMove to determine the position of the cursor relative to the button and calculate the desired cursor pointing in that direction. Otherwise, it would be much more complicated to edit the cursor image itself to rotate it in the required direction (as in the example you gave, they create a calculated SVG to be used as a cursor).